# A software to create 3D animations

Tags: 3d, animation

Could someone please suggest which software is used to create these 3D animations:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSWm_nprfqE

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The creator's YouTube page](https://www.youtube.com/c/LearnEngineering/about) mentions that they use software like

> Blender, Affinity Photo & HitFilm Pro